# Find out whether a window has a menu bar

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I want to know if it possible to gain the information, whether there is a menu in a Windows window or not.

This information would be used as [`AdjustWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632665%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)'s 3rd parameter. I don't want to have to save this information on my own if possible.

Comment: I recommend searching the internet using keywords "MSDN C++ detect menu"

Comment: If [`GetMenu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns `NULL` then there is no standard menu.

Comment: Aha.. I was searching MSDN ... but never found the Menu reference.. Thanks guys!

Comment: @fodinabor you may also want to keep [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030911-00/?p=42553) in mind; `AdjustWindowRect()` does not handle menus that wrap to multiple lines.

Comment: It is also possible for a window to use a custom menu bar that is not a standard menu, so these APIs would not be able to take that into account anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the window is already created, you can call [GetMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640.aspx), passing the window's handle. As explained in the documentation:

> If the specified window has no menu, the return value is NULL.

If, on the other hand, you need to know, whether a window that hasn't been created yet will have a menu by default<sup>1)</sup>, you can query the class info by calling [GetClassInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633578.aspx), and compare the returned [WNDCLASS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576.aspx)' *lpszMenuName* member. Again, as the documentation explains:

> If this member is NULL, windows belonging to this class have no default menu.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Note that a window can still have a menu added or removed at runtime by calling [SetMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647995.aspx).*